# PageLoad, Query String and Gridview - Retrieving Customer Orders

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pageload

I am trying to retrieve order information from my order database table specific to each customer using gridview and querystring

When a user logs in, i would like them to see all their orders. I have an order table which is binded to a gridview using querystring of 'customerid'

c#

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FoodDealsConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [customerid], [orderid], [menuname], [menuprice] FROM [Order] WHERE ([customerid] = @customerid)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="customerid" QueryStringField="customerid" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Page Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [orderid], [orderdate], [menuname], [menuprice], [quantity], [isdelivered] FROM [order] WHERE ([customerid] = " + Request.QueryString["customerid"];            
}
```

When i try this, nothing comes up. The gridview does not show up but when i put 
?customerid=5 at the end of the page link, it displays perfectly

Comment: the closing bracket ) is not put in your page load query

Comment: Please don't use inline SQL like this. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @ray i have closed the bracket, and it still won't display. I also tried removing the brackets completely - same issue. I'm just learning asp.net and have no clue on how to achieve the required result.

Comment: well Request.QueryString["customerid"] is null on page load and when you append the url only it is having value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether customerid is empty or not in page load event.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
      {
      if (Request.QueryString["customerid"] != null)
       {
       SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT [orderid], [orderdate], [menuname], [menuprice], [quantity], [isdelivered] FROM [order] WHERE [customerid] = " + Request.QueryString["customerid"].ToString(); 
       }
      }
     }
```

Then your grid view should be like below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvL" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"/>
```

Comment: This worked for me. The customerid was empty in the pageload event and i have fixed it. Thanks